# Resize a canvas image on click and center that with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, resize

How is it possible to zoom a photo contained in a `<canvas>` tag?
In particular I'd like to zoom in on the photo at the point the user clicked.

The zoom is not difficult to do:

```
img.width = img.width + 100;
img.height = img.height + 100;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height);
```

The problem is that I would also like to center the zoomed image in the point of the click, like a normal magnifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [[Working demo](http://jsbin.com/ejogi4/8)]

**Data**

- Resize by: `R`
- Canvas size: `Cw`, `Ch`
- Resized image size: `Iw`, `Ih`
- Resized image position: `Ix`, `Iy`
- Click position on canvas: `Pcx`, `Pcy`
- Click position on original image: `Pox`, `Poy`
- Click position on resized image: `Prx`, `Pry`

**Method**

1. Click event position on canvas -> position on image: `Pox = Pcx - Ix`, `Poy = Pcy - Iy`
2. Position on image -> Pos on resized image: `Prx = Pox * R`, `Pry = Poy * R`
3. `top = (Ch / 2) -  Pry`, `left = (Cw / 2) - Prx`
4. `ctx.drawImage(img, left, top, img.width, img.height)`

**Implementation**

```
// resize image
I.w *= R;
I.h *= R;

// canvas pos -> image pos
Po.x = Pc.x - I.left;
Po.y = Pc.y - I.top;

// old img pos -> resized img pos
Pr.x = Po.x * R;
Pr.y = Po.y * R;

// center the point
I.left = (C.w / 2) - Pr.x;
I.top  = (C.h / 2) - Pr.y;

// draw image
ctx.drawImage(img, I.left, I.top, I.w, I.h);
```